# Is incremental data loading supported in Alibaba QuickBI? If supported then how can we achieve it?

Tags: cloud, data-warehouse, alibaba-cloud

How to incrementally load data in Quick BI from the external database without any third party ETL tool?

Because there is no ETL support as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Again you need to wait for the **Data Lake Analytics** to be launched. This will not only solve your requirement, but this will also bridge the gap between the BI products and the DB's (the incremental support)